# Embed bundle into bundle using maven bundle plugin

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

So I'm wondering if there is a possibility to embed bundle into other bundle. I know that I could just put it into OSGi container, but in my scenario let's assume that I cannot do that.

I have full access to the code of both bundles, Bundle A has dependency to Bundle B.

Bundle B contains some OSGi services and components, which require configuration.

I'm wondering if there is a way to embed Bundle B into Bundle A in a way, that all components and services of Bundle A and Bundle B are visible in the OSGi container (for example under /system/console/components or /system/console/configMgr).
I know that this sounds tricky.

Probably Bundle B would have to be installed in the OSGi container as a bundle by Bundle A. Is that even possible? Maybe if not with maven bundle plugin, then maybe something else?

Apache Felix is mine OSGi container

Comment: To be honest, I do not really understand your problem, question and the use-case behind it. Could you please explain it in a practical way? Also, it seems that the "I'm wondering if..." sentence is unfinished.

Comment: I fixed the sentence. It's just complicating our process (having two separate bundles). That's the main reason.